# meteor installation error on mac OS X - El Capitan

Tags: cordova, ssl, curl, meteor, osx-elcapitan

Trying to install meteor on a fresh El Capitan installation with latest updates and Xcode installed.
The installation runs to 20% / 30% and than after a long time the following error occurs:

```
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
tar: (Empty error message)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Installation failed.
```

or this:

```
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
.meteor/packages/babel-compiler/.6.8.2.3odh20++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-traverse/package.json: (Empty error message)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Installation failed.
```